# How to get calendar date of today and move towards

Tags: ios, date

I know how to display today month with year using label .i use this code.

```
// show the present month
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat=@"MMMM";
    NSString * monthString = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date] capitalizedString];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat=@"yyyy";
    NSString * yearString = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date] capitalizedString];
    dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ,%@",monthString,yearString];
```

This above code will display the Present month with year. But what i need is. I need to do like below image

1..[image]

So `todays date is 29th Dec` and it should `start with 29Dec` and should display next`6 days date`.Like wise when user open on `tomorrow` like say `on 30th dec`. I need to disply like below image:

2..[image]

Like wise when user open my app on `31 Dec` it should display like this.

3..[image]

So when ever user open my app that `currrent date` alone should be in `first` with continuous on `next 6 days date`.

Please help me how to do that.I am new to ios. Your help will be very usefull for me to know more.Thanks

EDITED:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize flabel;
@synthesize slabel;
@synthesize tlabel;
@synthesize folabel;
@synthesize fivlabel;
@synthesize sixlabel;
@synthesize sevenlabel;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.


    NSArray *labelArray = @[flabel, slabel, tlabel, folabel, fivlabel,sixlabel, sevenlabel ];
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"ddMMM";
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:i toDate:today options:nil];
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)labelArray[i];
        label.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate];
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code creates the date in format `ddMMM` for today and the next 6 following days. Put the labels in an array and assign the dates to the labels by index.

```
NSArray *labelArray = @[firstDateLabel, secondDateLabel ...   ];

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"ddMMM";
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
  NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:i toDate:today options:nil];
  UILabel *label = (UILabel *)labelArray[i];
  label.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate];
}
```

However it doesn't consider potential daylight saving changing problems. The current date should be adjusted to a safe time where no problems can occur.

Comment: So where i can add that date with my 7 labels.text

Comment: i am getting error in last line. `labelArray[i].text = ..`  error is = `property text not found on object of type id`

Comment: i am not getting any date ..my uilabel are in blank. seemy updated post

Comment: please see my updated post. i am not getting any date in my uilabel

Comment: check if the labels are connected in Interface Builder and synthesizing properties is obsolete since Xcode 5.

Comment: yes ,its connected and then only i did @synthesis for all uilabel

Comment: `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is certainly not the right place.

Comment: ohhhh oopssss... sorry ...yes its working fine.... So if i opened tomorrow also it will show 31dec right??

Comment: Yes if your time zone is at least UTC +5, otherwise 30dec ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at NSCalendar and the section on calendrical calculations.

You need to fetch the current calendar.

Load the month/day/year components from your starting date. (Today?)

Set the hours value of your date components to 12 (to avoid problems with dates that change from daylight savings time to standard time, days when leap seconds are added, etc.)

Use dateFromComponents to get an NSDate for noon on the day in question. Let's call that noonDate.

Use 'dateByAddingUnit:value:toDate:options:' to add a day to noonDate:

Feed the result of dateByAddingUnit:value:toDate:options: to your date formatter to display it in localized version of your desired display format.

Comment: All of that stuff to make noon date is unnecessary if you use `dateByAddingUnit` with `.Day` to get the next date.

Comment: please explain with some code. I a new to ios.Please do code explain

Comment: Take a look at the Xcode docs. Search the Xcode help system on "Calendrical calculations". Try to work out what I described. If you are unable to get it to work, update your question with the code that you've tried and I or someone else will help you debug it, but you're not going to learn much if we give you code that you can copy/paste.

Comment: You got several useful answers, and responded to each one with "give me code." This is not a "write my code for me" service. Show a little effort. I gave you a step-by-step outline of what you need to do. If you'd like to **HIRE ME** to write your code for you then we can talk, but I'm expensive, and busy.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>you didn't tag your question objective-c, so I wrote a swift code, as it is so much more convenient to use playgrounds.</sub>

To avoid DST and similar pitfalls, I am using NSDateComponents for the calculation.

The code results in a array containing the labels.

```
import UIKit
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let now = NSDate()

var dates = [NSDate]()
for i in 0..<7 {
    let comps = cal.components([.Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: now)
    comps.day += i
    dates.append(cal.dateFromComponents(comps)!)
}

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dMMM"
let labels = dates.map { (date) -> UILabel in
    let dateSting = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
    let l = UILabel()
    l.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    l.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    l.text = dateSting
    l.sizeToFit()
    return l
}
```

Comment: i am zero in swift. i am very starter for ios. please provide in objective c

Comment: honestly: Your attitude is unbearable.

Comment: if you give me in objectivc that will be helpful

Comment: If you don't change your attitude drastically you will never master objective-c or any other language.